# Phishing email with encoded url params

Tags: http, javascript, phishing, encoding, obfuscation

I received a phishing email with the following format:

> hxxp://<%legitimateSite%>/~!@%23$%25%5e&*()_+~!@%23$%25%5e&*()*+~!@%23$%25%5e&*()*+~!@%23$%25%5e&*()_+~!@%23$%25%5e&*()*+~!@%23$%25%5e&*()*+~!@%23$%25%5e&*()_+~!@%23$%25%5e&*()*+~!@%23$%25%5e&*()*+~!@%23$%25%5e&*()_+~!@%23$%25%5e&*()*+~!@%23$%25%5e&*()*+/

but I can't make out what `~!@%23$%25%5e&*()` is - is it an obfuscated js function? I see traces of this string on google, but nothing concrete as to what it does.

It translates to this:

> "/~!@#$%^&*()_+~!@#$%^&*()*+~!@#$%^&*()*+~!@#$%^&*()_+~!@#$%^&*()*+~!@#$%^&*()*+~!@#$%^&*()_+~!@#$%^&*()*+~!@#$%^&*()*+~!@#$%^&*()_+~!@#$%^&*()*+~!@#$%^&*()*+~!@#$%^&*()_+~!@#$%^&*()*+~!@#$%^&*()*+~!@#$%^&*()_+~!@#$%^&*()*+~!@#$%^&*()*+~!@#$%^&*()_+/"

Would that be just a path to a index.php file to a malicious file download?

A similar thread online:

GET /%21@%23$%25%5E&%2A%28%29%29%28%2A&%5E%25$%23@%21/Review%20/ApproveDocument/Office%20365_files/shellg2coremincss_ba45585d.css HTTP/1.1

Comment: That's the result of typing the top row of a standard US keyboard with shift on (although the asterisk at shift 8 isn't easily visible because Stack treats it as markdown for italic), and almost certainly just convenient dummy/filler text. Your similar thread is typing most of the top row then going back.

Answer (score 1):

About the codification in your URL :"/~!@#$%^&()*+~!@#$%^&()+~!@#$%^&*()+~!@#$%^&()*+~!@#$%^&()+~!@#$%^&*()+~!@#$%^&()_+~!@#$%^&()+~!@#$%^&*()+~!@#$%^&()*+~!@#$%^&()+~!@#$%^&*()+~!@#$%^&()*+~!@#$%^&()+~!@#$%^&*()+~!@#$%^&()_+~!@#$%^&()+~!@#$%^&*()+~!@#$%^&*()_+/" I think that it is formed part of the path of the file suspected.

I think that this maybe is Phishing, I shearch the URL and finded this site:

https://urlquery.net/report/284aaf9f-1419-462f-86b3-392532e12237

It say that was report for a firewall because find a suspected trafic data.

You can test the host in virustotal for read the reports and have a major know of what happen and assurance if is malicious URL (the more probability is yes).